# Saving bounds of mapbox window in localStorage and then loading them on refresh/reload

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, bounds

I am using mapbox-gl-js for my project.
currently, it's working perfectly except that when I reload, the map goes back to the initial bounds that I have set.
I want that when the page refreshes, the mapbox goes back to the bounds from where the page was reloaded.

For this, i tried saving bounds into localStorage, but somehow it isnt working.
I have made an if condition, that if the bounds are present in localstorage, use these bounds otherwise get bounds from mapbox built in function.

```
retrieveMapData() {
    const savedBounds = localStorage.getItem('bounds');
    if (savedBounds) {
      return savedBounds;
    } else {
      this.bounds = this.getMap().getBounds();
    }
    this.createPolygon();

  }

  createPolygon() {
    localStorage.setItem('bounds', this.bounds);
    this
      .mapDataManager
      .getData(this.bounds)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.setSource('markerSource', this.prepareGeoJsonData(data));
      });
  }
```

I expect the mapbox to check if bounds exist in localStorage, if there is, load those bounds, if not, load the bounds from built in function.

currently, the if condition is totally not working.

Comment: not working as in savedBounds is null? or something else?

Comment: Actually, the issue is i am getting the bounds, but i need to convert them to coordinates and center the map on it.

How can i convert bounds to coordinates?

Comment: Try using `bounds.getCenter()` or even better `map.getCenter()` if it's a bounds or map object.

Comment: map.getBounds().toArray() ?

Comment: Or even try hash: true as a map option

Comment: Hello @cb64

I used map.getCenter() & got my work done.

Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I came through is:

We need to focus on the center of the map rather than bounds.

So i simply used **getCenter()** to get center of the map, and saved it in localStorage

Now, the bounds are automatically calculated and updated.

Here is the working code:

```
this.mapInstance = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      minZoom: 0,
      maxZoom: 18,
      center: this.getCenterOfMap(),
      zoom: this.getZoomValueOfMap(),
      style: this.style.streets
    });

getCenterOfMap () {
    try {
      this.savedCenter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('center'));
    } catch (exception) {
      console.log('Exception: ', exception);
    }
    if (this.savedCenter) {
      return this.savedCenter;
    } else {
      return this.defaultCenter;
    }
  }
```